# Regex to find all quotes between square brackets

Tags: java, regex

Seems pretty simple but I can't find anything that works.  Just want to capture all double quotes between square brackets so I can replace them with an empty string.  The values between the square brackets are always between [0-9].

Thanks for your help.

Input

```
    "someText"=["1111","2222"]
```

Output

```
    "someText"=[1111,2222]
```

Comment: You should use a JSON parser for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my case array elements will always be integers just wrapped in quotes. No special characters will be between the quotes, just [0-9].

Since you have no nested brackets, you can *lookahead* of a quote for a closing bracket without an intervening opening bracket:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(args[0].replaceAll("\"(?=[^\\[]*])", ""));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions are a tool that works when the input is **regular**. That is a specific bit of jargon, with a very specific meaning.

So, if the input you have is *not* **regular**, a regular expression cannot parse this. This format looks like JSON. And here's the bad news: JSON is not regular :( You just can't parse it with regexes. You write me a regexp that seems to work, I'll make you some valid JSON that your regexp replacer will mess up on.

You could fix it by adding bizarre caveats to what JSON can be input into your convoluted regex, but it seems like a much, much better idea to add a JSON parser to your code and use that.

Comment: In my case array elements will always be integers just wrapped in quotes.  No special characters will be between the quotes, just [0-9].  So I can capture all quotes with (") but not all quotes between [ and ]?  Thanks again.